# What are some basic tenets of interface design?

Tags: user-interface, interface

I am putting together some mock-ups of my first real interface and I am left wondering: What are some basic tenets of good user interface design?  I am looking for something like a bullet list summary and maybe some resources that might be useful for each tenet.

Comment: Tenets? Tenants tend to be rowdy and leave a mess.

Comment: you mean things like clean look, i.e. not cluttered with extraneous information.  equal sized buttons.  consistant spacing between components.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973/user-interface-design.

Comment: ...here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863/what-are-the-best-resources-for-designing-user-interfaces

Comment: Ok, highly recommend the book "Don't make me think" by Steve Krug I think... I know you want a nice easy list, but this is such an short easy book to read with so many good practises - will be well worth the money

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Don't make me think!",  the title and [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107) are extremely useful when designing a UI.
Some of my favorite sections from it include:

- Create a clear visual hierarchy.
- Conventions are your friend.
- Happy talk must die.
- Instructions must die.
- Four reasons why I love tabs.
- The trouble with Rollovers.
- Farmers vs. Cowmen.
- The myth of the "Average" user.

Answer (score 6):

Nielsen provides [this](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html) list - which I would generally agree with

- Visibility of system status
- Match between system and the real
  world
- User control and freedom
- Consistency and standards
- Error prevention
- Recognition rather than recall
- Flexibility and efficiency of use
- Aesthetic and minimalist design
- Help users recognize, diagnose, and
  recover from errors
- Help and documentation

Comment: Ask Tog has a good list too- http://www.asktog.com/basics/firstPrinciples.html

Comment: Yes but have you seen Nielsens website? Shocking! (IMO) http://www.useit.com/ 

-- Lee

Comment: It's not to my taste either ;-) good advice though...

Comment: @Lee Englestone - "Do as I say, not as I do."

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't interrupt the user with pop-up dialogs. 
   Show some feedback that the user can see and provide a way for them to deal with the issue when they choose to.
2. "The principle of least surprise".
3. Apply sensible defaults
4. Show response to user inputs within half a second.

Comment: +1 for "Show response to user inputs within half a second."

Comment: I would actually argue that half a second is too long.  I can't find the research at the moment, but humans recognize delay in less than that.  However, to be more generic, I would say, "Show response within a reasonable amount of time for the system in question."  There are times that fast responses aren't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I'd put consistency up there

-- Lee

Comment: Yes- as long as you are also aware of foolish consistency- http://www.scottberkun.com/essays/5-how-to-avoid-foolish-consistency. A good example of useful inconsistency is the back/forward buttons in FireFox- they are deliberately inconsistent.

Comment: How is that inconsistency useful?  I always check "Use Small Icons" simply so they *are* consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget keyboard accessibility, and more generally accessibility for vision-impaired people (this is why a great many cool-looking UIs actually suck).

Also, Alan Cooper (of Visual Basic fame) said "don't put *might* before *will*", which means you shouldn't make it easy for people to do the things they *might* do while making it difficult for them to do the things they *will* do with your software.

Answer (score 3):

If you read Asimov, you'll find this easy to remember: *an interface should not, through action or inaction, allow the user's work to be inadvertently destroyed*.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exactly meet your requirements for a bullet list, but I'd still recommend reading Mark Miller's [The Essence of Great UI - An Overview](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/02/05/the-essence-of-great-ui-an-overview.aspx), [Why is Great UI so hard to achieve?](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/02/06/why-is-great-ui-so-hard-to-achieve.aspx), [Great UI, Clarity, and Information Relevance](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/02/11/great-ui-clarity-and-information-relevance.aspx), [Great User Interfaces, Clarity, and Information in Parallel](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/02/17/great-user-interfaces-clarity-and-information-in-parallel.aspx) and [Great UI: Clarity and Color on the Presentation Layer](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/02/26/great-ui-clarity-and-color-on-the-presentation-layer.aspx).

He also talks about some of the same concepts in the [dnrTV](http://www.dnrtv.com/) episodes [Mark Miller on The Science of a Great User Experience Part 1](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=112) and [Part 2](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=123).

Answer (score 2):

Joel Spolsky (who is co-creator of SO :) ) [has a book called "User Interface Design for Programmers"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1893115941) as well as a series of articles on his website (Joel On Software) related to that book.

Another great resource to start with is [Jacob Nielsen's usablity website](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html).

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order (and off the top of my head):

- Convention over consistency
- Affordance (make it clear from the appearance how and what something does)
- Avoid modes
- Allow the user to create a correct mental model
- Protect the data (make it hard to be destructive)

Answer (score 2):

## Know your users.

- Spend time with them experiencing what they currently do without your software / changes.
- Get them to try and use as earlier prototype as feasible - maybe it's just paper, see
  how they react.
- Keep pushing your prototypes in front of them as development progresses.

Answer (score 1):

The one that I always try to remember is "7 items (max) to a page / form."  It came up in my GUI class in college (7 or 8 years ago now).

I'm reminded of a web comic where they had an Apple design followed by Google design (both very simple) followed by "our" design with dozens of items littering the form.

Comment: It's on xkcd somewhere - but I can't find the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Go and read [Controlling Your Environment Makes You Happy](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html) and then read [Don't Make Me Think! A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107).

Keep it simple, don't ignore convention and mimic sites/programs that work well.

Answer (score 1):

User interfaces are frequently for software developers or similarly tech-savvy people, not just laymen.  If yours is such an interface, you can benefit from being a user as well as the author.

1. Write the interface.
2. Put it away for a while, preferably long enough that you forget exactly how it works.
3. Use it to do something when you're in a bit of a hurry, or otherwise distracted.
4. Things will break, or force you to do things manually that weren't covered.  For each one, write a bug/feature report.  (If you're in that hurry, write just enough to remind you later.)
5. Fix/address each report.
6. Go to step 2.

This experience will give you insights to writing better interfaces, some of which may extend to laymen as well as the tech-savvy.  Beware, however; not every feature that is good for devs is good for non-devs.  Steps 2 and 3 are intended to get you into that non-dev mindset, and get you most of the way; for the last mile, there's no substitute for a real user.

Answer (score 1):

Using real people: Test, test, test.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed these:

http://www.asktog.com/basics/firstPrinciples.html

http://www.ambysoft.com/essays/userInterfaceDesign.html